# Error in installing GCC on MAC

Tags: gcc, rpy2

I am trying to install GCC on macOS with the commands below. But it is never completing and stuck at make. Any idea what can be done to complete the installation?

```
brew install gcc
sudo chown -R $USER /usr/local/
brew link --overwrite gcc
```

Comment: Your command isn't valid as is; are there newlines or semicolons between the individual commands?

Comment: How do you know it is stuck? Are all CPU cores idle? Is there no progress indication at all?

Comment: Is there anything in the log files (at ~/Library/Logs/Homebrew/gcc/ ) to indicate where things are stuck?